# Reading Image file in Opencv without ext

Tags: opencv

I am trying to download an image from URL, but it's difficult to get the complete file name and extension.

Currently, I save the downloaded image with any name and without an extension.

```
            with open(path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(request.content)
```

I then use opencv to read this image which has no extension and it works. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

opencv tries magic numbers / signatures for known image formats:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)

Implementation details:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/666be238d84c339993bf18c0798d27afd420d6be/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp#L209